# Map objects in array and show date if condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapping

```js
var data = [
{
 from: "2017-04-21T12:00:00",
 to: "2017-04-22T18:00:00",
 period: "2"
},
{
 from: "2017-04-21T18:00:00",
 to: "2017-04-22T00:00:00",
 period: "3"
},
{
 from: "2017-04-22T00:00:00",
 to: "2017-04-22T06:00:00",
 period: "0"
},
{
 from: "2017-04-22T06:00:00",
 to: "2017-04-22T12:00:00",
 period: "1"
}];
```

```html
<div data-day="today">
  <p>Today</p>
  <li>12:00 - 18:00: rain</li>
  <li>18:00 - 00:00: clouds</li>
</div>

<div data-day="2017-04-22">
  <p>22. april 2017</p>
  <li>00:00 - 06:00: sun</li>
  <li>06:00 - 12:00: snow</li>
</div>
```

I'm getting data from a weather service, where each day is divided into four periods: `0, 1, 2, 4`.

Each object where period is `0`, is the start of a new day. For this I want to show the date field `from` in the date format `DD. MM. YYYY HH:MM`

For objects where period is not `0`, I only need to show `from` in a time format: `HH:MM`. I'm using Momentjs to parse the dates, but need input on how to group each day.

Is mapping the objects the way to go, or does anyone have any good suggestions on how to achieve this?

First object will always be the current period, so this can vary.

```
{
    from: "2017-04-21T12:00:00",
    to: "2017-04-22T18:00:00",
    period: "2",
    forecast: "rain"
},
{
    from: "2017-04-21T18:00:00",
    to: "2017-04-22T00:00:00",
    period: "3",
    forecast: "clouds"
},
{
    from: "2017-04-22T00:00:00",
    to: "2017-04-22T06:00:00",
    period: "0",
    forecast: "sun"
},
{
    from: "2017-04-22T06:00:00",
    to: "2017-04-22T12:00:00",
    period: "1",
    forecast: "snow"
},
etc...
```

So for this I want to output a new div for each new day. The first objects until the first period=0 could have the data-day "today". Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<div data-day="today">
   <p>Today</p>
   <li>12:00 - 18:00: rain</li>
   <li>18:00 - 00:00: clouds</li>
</div>

<div data-day="2017-04-22">
   <p>22. april 2017</p>
   <li>00:00 - 06:00: sun</li>
   <li>06:00 - 12:00: snow</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Click the `<>` to show a [mcve] and expected output

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Please show us your expected output.

Comment: I'm maybe terrible at explaining, but for each object where period is equal to 0, I want to show the date. Else, only show the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for it:

```
var firstitem = $.grep(allitems, item => (item.period ==0))[0]
```